# Position fixed on div element

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

I am trying to give position fixed to the following div. But when i add position:fixed to css the element just disappears. Any suggestions will be appreaciated. Thanks!

Victoria

web and code below

http://vtwg.eu/ZMT/untitled3.html

```
<div id="book-now">
<a href="mailto:musictours@zzkrecords.com?subject=Music_Tours"><img 
src="book_now.png" alt="" width="90"></img></a>
</div>


#book-now{

background-image: url("back_2.png");
background-repeat: repeat;
text-align: right;
padding-right: 60px;
padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to get it to be fixed in the same spot no matter where you scroll or do you want it right below the slider?

Comment: hi, I ll would like the object to be right below the slider...and thtat you keep seeing it while u scroll down. am i answering ur question correctly? if there is an easier solution i m open to suggestions :) .thanks!!!!!!

Comment: you only want the yellow book image fixed right? without this dark background? then i would suggest to remove the book fondo and book now div and only position the link containing the image. with : position:fixed; top :  250px (more or less); right : 0;

Comment: or position book now as mentioned above and remove the background image

Comment: @VictoriaG that is one heck of a beautiful website.

Comment: @YashYadav, Olivier Krull , thanks you both for your complete answers, everything worked correctly now :) :) best!

Comment: @VictoriaG.I need to get in touch with you regarding some web design. Can I contact you ?

Comment: @YashYadav Hi there! yeah sure, does my email show up in my profile? if not victoria@vtwg.eu

Comment: @YashYadav Hi! Unfortunately client wants to place this object  700 px from top... and apparently when I do that object just disappears...any clues why ...it seems to happen with any position over 600px from top :/

Comment: @OlivierKrull Hi! Unfortunately client wants to place this object  700 px from top... and apparently when I do that object just disappears...any clues why ...it seems to happen with any position over 600px from top :/

Comment: @VictoriaG. Of course it will disappear because browser window has height approximately 642px and the image has its own height of 120 px So, If you put value of top > (approx) 540 . It will start to disappear , i.e go lower than bottom of window.

Comment: @VictoriaG. If you know JQuery you can do this easily by toggleClass.If you don't then put this as a separate question and provide us the link to it here so that I can give you easy code that you can copy into your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed elements are `fixed` in the browser . You have to define **where you want it to be fixed** by giving values of it `top` and `right` property

```
  position:fixed;
  top: 100px;
  right: 100px;
```

Comment: @OlivierKrull please clarify what's the problem ? .You want it to be fixed .It has to be fixed **somewhere** . What is the end result you want, can you clarify?

Comment: No problem man, i just agreed with your answer. (i didn't ask the question).

Comment: @OlivierKrull ok sorry. I thought this was your initial idea and you wanted a better one.

Comment: @OlivierKrull LOL i thought I have answered your question .Sorry. It is asked by Victoria . :)

Comment: without `width` and `height`  settings this won't be enough / will remain invisible - see my answer + examples below...

Comment: Yes, but @Johannes in that case its an image having width and height already , so I skipped that.

Answer (score 0):

If an element has fixed position, you have to define not only its position with settings for `top` or `bottom` and `left` or `right` (default is the upper left corner of the window), but also a `width` and`height` -  otherwise it will have zero width and height and therefore remain invisible.

addition: It there are position settings for all four mentioned settings ( `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`), you don't need width and height, since those are defined by those positions.

an example:

```css
.x {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/60x40/fa7");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
```

and without width and height settings (i.e. invisible):

```css
.x {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    left: 100px;;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/60x40/fa7");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes, also helpfull info!

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately client wants to place this object  700 px from top... and apparently when I do that object just disappears...any clues why ...it seems to happen with any position over top: 600px :/

Answer (score 0):

When you use position:fixed, it is for the browser window.
You need to put top, left, right, or bottom value.
Such as:

```
#book-now{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    background-image: url("back_2.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nina, thanks so much for your answer! it also worked out! :)